# What's the relationship of two "self" params in two classes

Tags: subclass, superclass

```
class Filter:
    def init(self):
        self.blocked=[]
    def filter(self,sequence):
        return [x for x in sequence if x not in self.blocked]

class Spamfilter(Filter):
    def init(self):
        self.blocked=['spam']
```

The block below is the result of execution:

```
>>> f=Filter()
>>> f.init()
>>> f.filter([1,2,3])
[1, 2, 3]
>>> 
>>> 
>>> s=Spamfilter()
>>> s.init()
>>> s.filter(['spam','spam','spam','eggs','bacon','spam'])
['eggs', 'bacon']
>>>
```

question 1:How does the codes work,help to list the execution process.
question 2:What's the actually mean of the "self" param.why I need to init 
           it?

question 3:Is the "self.blocked=[]" an assignment? To give an empty
           sequence to the ...variable?or a method,or sth...?